# integers become floats when concatenating pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes:

df1 is an empty dataframe:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Start','End','Duration'])

df1
Out[1]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Start, End, Duration]
Index: []
```

df2 contains:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([None] * 3).reshape(-1,3),columns=['Start','End','Duration'])
df2['Start'] = 483
df2['End'] = 523
df2['Duration'] = 0.8

df2
Out[2]: 
       Start  End  Duration
    0    483  523      0.8


df2['Start']
Out[3]: 
0    483
Name: Start, dtype: int64
```

I want to concatenate the 2 dataframes:

```
df1= pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)[df1.columns.tolist()]
```

df1 is:

```
df1
Out[4]: 
   Start    End  Duration
0  483.0  523.0    0.8
```

As you can see now "Start" and "End" are float... is there a way to keep them int?

Comment: I think it is a bug report to https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Comment: This is not reproducible for me (using pandas 1.0.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df1[['Start','End']] = df1[['Start','End']].astype(int)
```

output:

```
   Start  End  Duration
0    483  523       0.8
```